# puppetlabs_mysql fails to import two sql scripts given as an array to the db class

Tags: mysql, module, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

This is so good but I would like to ask if the sql parameter to import sql scripts can receive an array as argument that is get two .sql file or more and still execute successfully, have tried to give it an array but it joins everything to one so that

```
      mysql::db{...
        sql => ["/tmp/1.sql","/tmp/2.sql",]
        ....
       }
```

it assumes the above to be

```
           /tmp/1.sql/tmp/2.sql
```

which is wrong is not possible .... is there a way for the puppetlabs mysql module to have two sql scripts imported at a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do it with `mysql::db`, either you concat the sql files yourself beforehand or run [the exec that `mysql::db` runs](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/blob/master/manifests/db.pp#L50)

```
  exec{ "${dbname}-import":
    command     => "/usr/bin/mysql ${dbname} < ${sql}",
    logoutput   => true,
    environment => "HOME=${::root_home}",
    refreshonly => $refresh,
    require     => Mysql_grant["${user}@${host}/${table}"],
    subscribe   => Mysql_database[$dbname],
  }
```

Comment: That, or send a patch upstream to add the desired capability.

Comment: Could you give an example to demonstrate this Thank you

Comment: that's what I posted, just replace the variables with your values